# NPM Nodejs crashes with BSOD

Tags: node.js, google-chrome, npm

So I'm getting a blue screen of death whenever I have "npm start" running for a reactjs app. It's an intermittent crash, i.e. it doesn't happen every time I run it nor are there any exact steps to duplicate the crash, but I'll try to explain below under what circumstances it happens.

1. Create a reactjs app using `create-react-app` npm module.
2. Start the app using `npm start`. Chrome window opens, webpack is listening to changes I make to the source files.
3. Change any source file, and save it. NPM compiles it, Chrome page refreshes, and I can see my changes.

The above things work fine as expected "normally", but once in a while, right after I save a file, the system crashes with a BSOD saying DRIVER_IRQL_NOT_EQUAL_TO_OR_GREATER_THAN (NETIO.SYS) There is no definite "step" or action other than saving the file, or refreshing Chrome that would cause this to happen, and it also doesn't happen every single time.

Here are the steps I took to find out/eliminate the root cause of this issue:

1. Disabled by AV (Symantec Endpoint Protection).
2. Use a different browser (Mozilla, hell, even IE).
3. Changed the system (used a different laptop, although the same type - Microsoft Surface on Windows 10)
4. Updated all drivers, etc. (Verified by my organization admins)
5. Closing all other programs, etc. that might potentially be interfering (Atom IDE, Eclipse, etc.)

The necessary conditions for the crash to happen are:

1. `npm start` must be running (webpack server on localhost:3000)
2. A browser window must be open connected to localhost:3000 (if no browser is connected, it doesn't crash even if you change and save the file 200 times - I checked). Also, doesn't matter which browser (Checked with Mozilla/Edge/Chrome)

I believe the crash happens when NPM is recompiling the files and serving it to the browser (asking it to refresh using some websockets), but I'm not an expert on NodeJS/NPM so I'm not sure.

I've been stuck on this issue for more than 2 weeks now. Any help would be really appreciated. Kindly let me know if more information is needed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue was with Symantec DLP (Data Loss Prevention) that was also installed on all our systems. The issue resolved itself after the admins added application exceptions for Nodejs, NPM, my reactjs project workspace paths.

Just posting this so that in case someone has a similar issue they can try this or remove Symantec DLP altogether.